# How can I set a list with different expiration of its child?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Now I need to make a IP black list demand.

When the administer add the ip address to the IP black list, the IP can not access the website within 2 hours.

In my opinion, I will use a ImemoryCache and set a expiration to store it. Meanwhile, one key of ImemoryCache can only store one object and set one expiration while there may be so many IP address here..

How can I set a list with different expiration of its child? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How can I set a list with different expiration of its child?

You could not set different expiration for the child if you cache the IP List with one key.

For a workaround, you may try to cache the ip independent like below:

```
    public IActionResult CreateCache()
    {
        string ip = "xx.xx";
        using (var entry = _memoryCache.CreateEntry(ip))
        {
            entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
    public IActionResult CheckCache()
    {
        string ip = "xx.xx";
        var exist = _memoryCache.TryGetValue(ip, out string value);
        return Ok();
    }
```